How could predict the affect of adding another element to an alloy in the terms of thermal conductivity and material wear resistance?
I'm interested in the effect on thermal conductivity and material wear resistance by adding different elements to an already high thermal conductivity metal like GRCop-42.
My main interests are in the metals:

Silver
Nickel
Tungsten or Hafnium

The reason is I am looking into rotating detonation engines and aerospike engines.
